# ZFC without Power Set, effect of adding well ordering or not.

Tags: set-theory

As $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms:

1. set existence
2. extensionality
3. foundation
4. restricted comprehension
5. pairing
6. union
7. collection (instead of replacement)
8. infinity
9. power set ($\mathsf{Pow}$)
10. well ordering ($\mathsf{AC}$)

I call $\mathsf{ZFC}$ the theory with {1,...,10},
$\mathsf{ZF}$ the theory with {1,...9}

$\mathsf{ZFC}$-{power set} is equivalent to $\mathsf{ZF}$-{power set} ?

What is the effect of adding well-ordering into $\mathsf{ZF}$-{power set}?

Intuitively it seems that without Power Set we don't have uncountable sets, so every infinite set would be enumerable, and this bijection could provide a well-order.

I am almost sure that well-ordering has no effect into {1-7}.

UPDATE: Add some format. Not sure if it makes a lot of diference but I took collection instead of replacement because of this ([Which set theories without the power set axiom are used occasionally?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409235/which-set-theories-without-the-power-set-axiom-are-used-occasionally))

Comment: It may be possible to get clever with union, specification, and replacement, to construct an uncountable set from infinity even without powerset; but that is just conjecture from me. Interesting question, however.

Comment: You can't prove well ordering in ZFC - power set  - well ordering. If you could, then you could prove it in ZFC - well ordering.

Comment: @Graviton No, you can't... e.g. the set of hereditarily countable sets is a model of ZFC-Power Set that satisfies "every set is countable".

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen that said, without Choice, there is a model of ZF in which an uncountable set is equal to the union of countably many countable sets (So maybe ZF-powerset is able to produce uncountables?). I suppose that's irrelevant here because choice is assumed, though.

Comment: @Graviton You can't get a *stronger* theory by *dropping* axioms. The set of hereditarily countable sets $\mathsf{HC}$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Pow}$ so a fortiori it also satisfies $\mathsf{ZF}-\mathsf{Pow}$. There's just no sense in which we can still produce uncountable sets without powerset.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I think you should turn your observatino about $\mathsf{HC}$ into an answer.

Comment: @Graviton Meanwhile, it is true - albeit silly - that $\mathsf{ZF}+\neg\mathsf{AC}$ proves the existence of an uncountable set: any non-well-orderable set (= counterexample to $\mathsf{AC}$) must a fortiori be uncountable.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You are correct assuming ZF is consistent. But ZF has a higher consistency strength then ZF - PowerSet.

Comment: @MarkSaving No, spaceisdarkgreen doesn't need any additional consistency hypothesis. If $M\models\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$ then $\mathsf{HC}^M$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC-Pow}$ + "Every set is countable," so $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$ (unless inconsistent) cannot prove "There is an uncountable set." Of course $\mathsf{HC}^M$ may be a class, instead of a set, in $M$, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was referring to his argument that we can’t prove choice from ZF - PowerSet because we can’t prove choice from ZF. This argument clearly assumes ZF is consistent.

Comment: @MarkSaving Ah, sorry, I misread that.

Comment: @MarkSaving Actually, that's an interesting problem: I don't immediately see a way to show that without assuming Con(ZF). The issue is that models of ZF-Pow might be too small for anything like symmetric extensions to work (take e.g. $L_{\omega_1}$ ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$, then $\mathsf{HC}^\mathcal{M}$ (= the substructure of $\mathcal{M}$ consisting of all objects which $\mathcal{M}$ thinks are hereditarily countable sets) is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC-Pow}$ + "Every set is countable." This can be verified in a very weak set theory (e.g. $\mathsf{KP}$) or reformulated in terms of consistency and proved in arithmetic (e.g. $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$). Consequently:

- In a precise sense, we do need powerset to prove the existence of an uncountable set: $\mathsf{ZFC-Pow}$ has models satisfying "Every set is countable" (assuming it is consistent in the first place). Dropping choice has nothing to do with this (although adding the negation of choice *does* - every countable set is a fortiori well-orderable, so $\mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$ does prove that there is an uncountable set). Of course, even $\mathsf{ZFC-Pow+\neg Pow}$ is still consistent with "There is an uncountable set," so your statement "without powerset we don't have uncountable sets" is still incorrect.
- In terms of consistency strength, there's no difference between $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$, $\mathsf{ZFC-Pow}$, and $\mathsf{ZFC-Pow}$ + "Every set is countable."

Interestingly, showing that $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}\not\vdash \mathsf{AC}$ is a bit more nuanced. Certainly (by Cohen) this is a consequence of $\mathsf{Con(ZF)}$, but this is rather overkill-y; can we get by just assuming $\mathsf{Con(ZF-Pow)}$ (which is a much weaker assumption)?

Embarrassingly, I don't see how to do this! The issue is that models of $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$ can be "too small" for the symmetric extension technique to work properly. Specifically, let $\alpha$ be the *second* smallest ordinal such that $L_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC-Pow}$. Then - unless I'm getting things wrong - $L_\alpha\models$ "$\mathsf{ZFC-Pow}$ has a transitive model but $\mathsf{ZF-Pow+\neg AC}$ does not have a transitive model." This shows that any argument for establishing the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF-Pow+\neg AC}$ relative to that of $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$ over a not-too-strong base theory must crucially involve non-well-founded constructions.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have any relation to the question, but I find a little disturbing that one could define the set of all sequences of natural numbers, without the need of PowerSet.

Comment: @Eduard I don't understand your comment. One can *define* $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ just fine without powerset (indeed, it's not clear to me what it means to use an axiom in a definition - they're grammatically different sorts of objects). One cannot *prove that it is a set* without powerset, though.

Comment: @Eduard Per your comments below, it seems you're interested in $\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$, not $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. In this case we don't need powerset to prove that it is a set; its set-hood already follows from Infinity + Replacement (fine, we also want Pairing in there).

Comment: I’ve thought about the matter for some time, and I haven’t found any way to exhibit a model of $ZF - PowerSet + \neg AC$ in ZFC so far. I was hoping I could show in $ZF$ that given any set $S$, there is a transitive model of $ZF - PowerSet$ containing $S$. Then work in $ZF + \neg AC$ and take $S$ to be a set which has no choice function. This proves the consistency of $ZF - PowerSet + \neg AC$. Apply absoluteness of 1st-order arithmetic to get the result in pure $ZF$. But I haven’t been able to make it work because so many nice facts about cardinals require choice.

Comment: Or rather, a set $S$ with no well-ordering, since having a choice function implies having a power set, which is too strong a notion.