# How hard is it to show $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}\not\vdash\mathsf{AC}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, axiom-of-choice

This is motivated by comments on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512125/zfc-without-power-set-effect-of-adding-well-ordering-or-not).

Let $T_0=\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$ and $T_1=\mathsf{ZF-Pow+\neg AC}$. (Note that there is [some subtlety](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2430) about what precisely $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}$ is; here, I adopt the convention which I believe is now standard that *collection* is used instead of *replacement*.)

In one sense it's easy to show that $T_1$ is consistent: since per Cohen we have $\mathsf{ZF}\not\vdash\mathsf{AC}$, a fortiori we cannot have $\mathsf{ZF-Pow}\vdash\mathsf{AC}$. However, this argument uses the assumption that $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent (what Cohen *actually* proved, in an appropriately weak base theory, was $\mathsf{Con(ZF)}\rightarrow\mathsf{Con(ZF+\neg AC)}$). Based on how such questions usually pan out I would argue that we should expect this to be massive overkill:

> Can we prove in $\mathsf{PA}$ *(or at absolute worst in $T_0$)*, that $\mathsf{Con(T_0)}\leftrightarrow\mathsf{Con(T_1)}$?

The issue is that forcing/symmetric extensions do not seem to be as useful in this context. For a concrete obstacle, let $\alpha$ be the *second* smallest ordinal such that $L_\alpha\models T_0$. Then (unless I'm missing something) $L_\alpha$ satisfies "There is a transitive model of $T_0$ but there is no transitive model of $T_1$," the key trick being **local countability**, so any proof of $\mathsf{Con(T_1)}$ from non-overkill assumptions must rely on nonstandard models.

Answer (score 3):

Work over $\mathsf{ZF^-}$, Zermelo-Frankel set theory without choice and with Collection. I will argue that $\mathsf{ZF^-}$ can interpret $\mathsf{ZF^-}$ with there is a non-well-orderable set of reals, by syntactically formulating the typical construction of the basic Cohen model over $\mathsf{ZF^-}$.
The focal point of the argument I will provide is that inductive definitions still work without Powerset.

*It should be better to clarify that the above argument can be purely syntactical, as we can treat forcing relations purely syntactic manner. Thus the argument given below shows $\mathsf{PRA}$ proves $\mathsf{Con}(T_0)$ proves $\mathsf{Con}(T_1)$, by the same idea that the usual forcing argument can be deemed as a proof of $\mathsf{Con(ZFC)\to Con(ZFC+\lnot CH)}$ over $\mathsf{PRA}$.*

We can see that the forcing relation is still definable from the remaining axioms of $\mathsf{ZF^-}$. The key fact is that using the inductive definition (introduced in Barwise's textbook) instead of constructing a hierarchy using Powerset.

Also, $\mathsf{ZF^-}$ proves the set of all partial functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$ is a set, so Cohen forcing  $\mathbb{P}=\operatorname{Col}(\omega\times\omega,2)$ exists. We will see that $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ can define the Basic Cohen model.

For any permutation $\pi$ over $\omega$, we can extend it as a permutation over $\mathbb{P}$ as

- $\operatorname{dom}(\pi(p))=\{(\pi(n),m)\mid (n,m)\in\operatorname{dom} p\}$, and
- $\pi(p)(\pi(n),m)=p(n,m)$.

Let $G$ be the class of all $\pi$ over $\mathbb{P}$. We can extend $\pi$ to a map from $\mathbb{P}$-names to $\mathbb{P}$-names, recursively by
$$\pi(\dot{x}) = \{(\pi(p),\pi(\dot{y})) \mid (p,\dot{y})\in \dot{x}\}.$$

However, we cannot correctly form the symmetric filter $\mathcal{F}$, so let us go down to earth and handle it concretely.

For a finite subset $e$ of $\omega$, define
$$\operatorname{fix}e = \{\pi\in G \mid \forall n\in e (\pi(n)=n)\}.$$
We cannot prove $\operatorname{fix}e$ is a set unless we know $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is a set. For each $\mathbb{P}$-name $\dot{x}\in V^\mathbb{P}$, define $$\operatorname{sym}_G(\dot{x})=\{\pi\in G\mid \pi(\dot{x})=\dot{x}\}$$
as we did over $\mathsf{ZF}$. Now let us call a $\mathbb{P}$-name $\dot{x}$ is *symmetric* if there is a finite subset $e\subseteq \omega$ such that $\operatorname{fix}e\subseteq \operatorname{sym}_G(\dot{x})$. Now we can define the class of all hereditarily symmetric names $\mathsf{HS}$.

Now consider the forcing relation $\Vdash^{\mathsf{HS}}$ obtained by restricting the range of quantifiers to $\mathsf{HS}$. Thus for example, for $\dot{x}\in{\mathsf{HS}}$,

- $p\Vdash^{\mathsf{HS}} \forall y\phi(y, \dot{x})$ if and only if for any for any $\dot{y}\in \mathsf{HS}$, $p\Vdash\phi(\dot{y},\dot{x})$,

and define the remaining part similarly to the syntactic definition of forcing. (Definition 5.7 of Karagila's [*Iterating Symmetric Extensions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06718) is relevant.) Then we can show that the empty condition $\mathsf{HS}$-forces all axioms of $\mathsf{ZF^-}$. Furthermore, we can prove that the name of the generic filter
$$\dot{G}=\{(p,\check{p})\mid p\in\mathbb{P}\}$$
is a set, and $\dot{G}\in \mathsf{HS}$. Hence we can internally argue under the $\mathsf{HS}$-forcing relation that (the empty condition forces) $\dot{G}$ produces a set of reals that is not well-orderable by following the typical argument.

Comment: Huh. I had no idea I've become the reference for the symmetric forcing relation. :|

Comment: @Asaf I linked it just because it was one of the references stating a syntactic formulation of a symmetric model. Are there any earlier references that mention $\Vdash^\mathsf{HS}$?

Comment: I mean, to some extent, Jech's 2006 version, in the paragraphs preceding Lemma 15.51.